# ¿Cómo sulucionar el problema de nombres de archivos con espacios en un bucle for? (CMD, Batch)

Tags: cmd, batch, bucle-for

Estoy guardando el contenido de un archivo usando este código.

```
for /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x in (Archivo.txt) do (set line=%%x)  & call :concadena
echo %TEXTO%
pause
goto :eof

:concadena
set TEXTO=%TEXTO%%line%
goto :eof
```

Funciona bien siempre que el nobre del archivo no contenga espacios, y falla si se pone el nombre del archivo con espacios o entre comillas.

-Si lo pongo entre comillas, por ejemplo así:

```
for /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x in ("Nombre Archivo.txt") do (set line=%%x)  & call :concadena
```

La salida que obtengo es el nombre del propio archivo **"Nombre Archivo.txt"**

-Si no pongo comillas, por ejemplo así:

```
for /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x in (Nombre Archivo.txt) do (set line=%%x)  & call :concadena
```

Me da el error: **El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo Nombre**

Pues eso, necesito leer archivos que ni siquiera están dento del mismo directorio del .bat y casi 100% seguro de que la ruta absoluta va a contener espacios.

¿Cómo se puede solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, acabo de encontrar una solución. Por lo visto hay una opción llamada **usebackq** que soluciona este problema. La cosa quedaria así:

```
for /f "Tokens=* usebackq Delims=" %%x in ("Nombre Archivo.txt") do (set line=%%x)  & call :concadena
echo %TEXTO%
pause
goto :eof

:concadena
set TEXTO=%TEXTO%%line%
goto :eof
```

Fuente: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006290/for-f-processing-filename-with-spaces

Answer (score 0):

Escapa los espacios con el simbolo "^".

Fuente: https://www.enmimaquinafunciona.com/pregunta/25186/como-puedo-escapar-de-espacios-en-la-linea-de-comandos-en-windows-sin-el-uso-de-comillas

Comment: Lo he puesto así (Nombre^ Archivo.txt) y sigue dandome el mismo error... ¿Alguna otra idea?

Comment: De todas formas gracias por responder montes18295. Se me habia olvidado!! :-)

Comment: Con y sin comillas?

Comment: De las dos formas

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenia el mismo problema.
Sin embargo adapte algo de lo tuyo a mi codigo y al parecer funciona.

---

for /F "delims=" %A IN (C:\Users\username\Desktop\prueba\lista1.txt) do dir /b "C:\Users\username\Desktop\prueba%A" // resultado encuentra el archivo

---

---

donde en lista.txt que se encuentra en la carpeta prueba, contiene el nombre del archivo.
nombre prueba.mp3                     //nombre del archivo

---

---

y el archivo se encuentra en la carpeta prueba
nombre prueba.mp3                      // archivo

saludos espero que te sirva.